# Proving that a strange function is integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For a point $x$ in the interval $[1, 2]$, define $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational and define $f(x) = 1/n$ if $x$ is rational and is expressed as $x = m/n$ for natural numbers $m$ and $n$ having no common positive integer divisor other than $1$. Prove that $f : [1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable. (Hint: First prove that given $\epsilon > 0,$ there are only a finite number of points $x$ in the interval $[1, 2]$ at which $f(x) \geq \epsilon.$)

**My attempt:**

The function $f$ is discontinuous at every rational number in $[1, 2]$ because

$$f\left(p/q\right) = 1/q \neq 0,$$

and there is not any sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $(x_{n}) \rightarrow p/q$ (which follows from the density of $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$).

Also the image sequence $(f(x_{n}))$ converges to $0$, but $f(p/q) \neq 0$ so $f$ is not continuous at rationals.

Now, we will show that $f$ is continuous at irrational points.

I'm also pretty sure that the function is continuous at every irrational point, but I'm not so sure about how to prove this, or how it would help me prove my statement.

I'm pretty sure I'm taking the wrong approach here because I haven't utilized the hint at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Lebesgue criterion?

Comment: If $a_n/b_n\to x$ where $x$ is irrational reduced, then you can show $b_n\to\infty$ (assuming reduced means $b_n>0$). Suppose $P\in\mathbb{N}$. If there did not exist and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we had $b_n>P$, then we could find $\{b_{n_k}\}$ such that $b_{n_k}\leq P$ for all $n_k$. Since $a_n/b_n$ converges it is bounded. Since $a_{n_k}/b_{n_k}$ is bounded, and $b_{n_k}$ is bounded we have $a_{n_k}$ bounded. Then there are only finitely many choices for $a_{n_k}/b_{n_k}$, hence there is a constant subsequence of $a_n/b_n$. So $a_n/b_n$ would converge to a rational.

Comment: I don't know which criterion. It's a first-semester real analysis book.

Comment: Using the "upper sum, lower sum" definition of Riemann integrability to prove this result is far, far easier than proving the "Lebesgue criterion".  This exact problem is included in calculus textbooks which have no mention of the Lebesgue criterion at all.

Comment: So, the hint is: given $\epsilon > 0$, show that there is a partition of $[1,2]$ such that the corresponding upper sum is ${} < \epsilon$.

Comment: I still cannot get anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to prove the result for for the function $g(x)=f(x+1);\ $ i.e. translate the interval to $[0,1]$. If the result holds for $g$, then it also holds for $f$. Now, if $x\in [0,1]$ is irrational, then $f(x)=0.$ Suppose $(r_n)$ is any sequence of numbers converging to $x$. If some $r_k$ is irrational, then $f(r_k)=0=f(x).$ So without loss of generality, we may assume that $r_n=m_n/j_n$ is rational in lowest terms, for all integers $n$. Now, (and here is why we translated the interval; it makes the following remark easier to prove) observe that $j_n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ (why?) and therefore $f(r_n)=1/j_n\to 0=f(x)$ as $n\to \infty.$ This implies that $f$ is continuous on the irrationals in $[0,1]$ and so by the Riemann-Lebesgue criterion, it is  Riemann integrable there.